# How To select a Value From Drop-Down using Selenium?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium

Given Below is a Piece of Code which denotes a Drop-Down.
I need to Select **Date** value in this Drop-down denoted By `<option value="1" label="Date">Date</option>`

```
<select id="type" class="text-input ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope ng-touched" ng-style="cssStyle" name="type" ng-if="!options.hidePlaceholder" ng-model="result.type" qmx-observe-value="text" ng-disabled="options.readonly" ng-options="obj.value as obj.text group by obj.groupby for obj in selectData" style="font-size: 13px; opacity: 1; width: 100%;">
    <option class="ng-binding" value="">----</option>
    <option value="0" selected="selected" label="Text">Text</option>
    <option value="1" label="Date">Date</option>
    <option value="2" label="Numeric">Numeric</option>
    <option value="3" label="Switch">Switch</option>
    <option value="4" label="Map Location Marker">Map Location Marker</option>
    <option value="5" label="Picker">Picker</option>
    <option value="6" label="List">List</option>
    </select>
```

Following Methods didn't work.

1.) selecting this value using *Select* by importing **org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select**

```
Select elm = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='type']/option[3]")));
  elm.selectByVisibleText("Date");
```

Console shows:

> Element should have been "select" but was "option"

2.) Clicking on the Drop-Down first to display option to be selected and then clicking on the option.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='type']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='type']/option[3]")).click();
```

Console shows:

> DEBUG Element is missing an accessible name: id: type, tagName:
>   SELECT, className: text-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid
>   ng-scope

3.) Using JavascriptExecutor to get the click.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='type']")).click();    
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='type']/option[3]")));
```

Console shows:

> DEBUG    Element is missing an accessible name: id: type, tagName:
>   SELECT, className: text-input ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid
>   ng-scope

4.) Using Mouse-Over on Option to be selected in Drop-down and then performing click on it.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='type']")).click();    
WebElement subdrop = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='type']/option[3]"));
        Actions action = new Actions(drive);
        action.moveToElement(subdrop).perform();
        Custom.Twait();
        action.click(subdrop).perform();
```

Console shows:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.UnsupportedCommandException: POST
>   /session/a37a745a-e40c-45a9-9760-8e01b451a017/moveto did not match a
>   known command (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information)

*I have also added Wait in Between where i'm using this code. Here for simplicity i did not include it.*

Need Help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first option selenium clearly saying **Element should have been "select" but was "option"**, means here you are providing the `xpath` for `option` while expecting only `xpath` for select.

Don't need to use other option as you provided, Just use your first option as below :-

```
Select elm = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("type")));
elm.selectByVisibleText("Date");
```

or `ByIndex`

```
elm.selectByIndex(2);
```

or `ByValue`

```
elm.selectByValue("1");
```

If your first option unfortunatly not work I prefer you to use your third option Using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
WebElement select = driver.findElement(By.id("type"));

((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("var select = arguments[0]; for(var i = 0; i < select.options.length; i++){ if(select.options[i].text == arguments[1]){ select.options[i].selected = true; } }", select, "Date");
```

Hope it will help you...:)

Comment: It didn't work. I'm currently using `sendKeys(keys.ARROW_DOWN)` and then `senKeys(keys.RETURN)` method to get that option selected which seems to be working but i would definitely like to know other means of achieving this objective.

Comment: that JavascriptExecutor code worked like a Charm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @PawanJuyal could you tell me why did first option not work??? is there exception???

Comment: conn0 -> [0,25,"findElements",{"element":"c1efa248-5a65-43ac-af75-47bd7d306429","using":"xpath","value":".//option[@value = \"2\"]"}]
1467883681756 conn0 <- [1,25,null,[{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"38f00c46-c8d1-4e43-ad5f-2d34d50441ce","ELEMENT":"38f00c46-c8d1-4e43-ad5f-2d34d50441ce"}]]
1467883681769  conn0 -> [0,26,"isElementSelected",{"id":"38f00c46-c8d1-4e43-ad5f-2d34d50441ce"}]
1467883681781 conn0 <- [1,26,null,{"value":false}]
1467883681787 conn0 -> [0,27,"clickElement",{"id":"38f00c46-c8d1-4e43-ad5f-2d34d50441ce"
1467883681835 conn0 <- [1,27,null,{}]

Comment: @PawanJuyal why are you providing `xPath` with `.//option[@value = "2"]`...you need to just find the select element as `By.id("type")` and provide it to `new Select()` to work as select box in selenium...

Comment: There was no clear Exception or i probably failed to understand the contents of Console. Anyways, could you please Explain the JavascriptExecutor code above?  I'm missing something there. If i change **arguments[1]** with **arguments[2]** and "Date" with "Numeric" in `if(select.options[i].text == arguments[1]){ select.options[i].selected = true; } }", select, "Date");` will the Drop-down be set to Numeric?

Comment: No need to change from `arguments[1] ` to `arguments[2]`.. you need to just replace `"Date"` to `"Numeric"` that's it...

Comment: I used `Select elm = new Select(drive.findElement(By.id("type")));
  elm.selectByValue("2");`  i haven't specified xpath. I just identified the Select element and then used selectByValue.

Comment: @PawanJuyal in `.executeScript()` expects two args where first is `String args` which is javascript and another  is `Object[] args` where first `args` is your `select box` element and another is **visible text option** which you want to select.. so every time you need to just change **visible text option**  which you want to select

Comment: excellent, this really helped me out, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In case you anyone looking solution in **Selenium - Python :** with JS call.

```
driver.execute_script("return document.getElementById('select id here').selectedIndex = '2'")
```

Answer (score 0):

The select class as used in other languages was not available in typescript. Click seems to work when used with xPath.

```
import { Builder, By, Key, Locator, TargetLocator, until } from 'selenium-webdriver';

async function example() {
  const driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
  await driver.get('http://localhost:5500/website/index.html');
  const xPath = '//*[@id="cars"]/option[3]';
  const element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
  await element.click();
}
```

Relevant HTML:

```
<label for="cars">Choose a car:</label>
<select name="cars" id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Basically our selector should target the option element and trigger Click event.