# Unable to select from dropdown

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have below code in HTML for dropdown

I have written below code in selenium

```
WebElement grp = driver_new.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/form/fieldset[5]/div[1]/select"));
Select se = new Select(grp);
se.selectByVisibleText("Aa");
```

But i am not getting an error bit not selecting any value.How to resolve it.
It clicks on the drop down and does not select item from that list.Please help

Comment: Can you share out the exact error message?

Comment: updated..please check

Comment: That error doesn't look to be related to the dropdown. Add in a system.out.println after your selectByInvisibleText to see if it actually thinks it's selected? Let me know.

Comment: You're exception is saying that it can't find element "//*[@id='new_user_vitals']/fieldset[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/a[3]/div/div/div[2]" . That element isn't in your selenium code that you shared out so the problem is either occuring before or after that. Add this line to the bottom of your selenium code System.out.println("Selected the option"); If that prints out in the console then the option was selected or atleast it thinks it's selected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How To select a Value From Drop-Down using Selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239278/how-to-select-a-value-from-drop-down-using-selenium)

Comment: It is printing, but i dont see any value selected in the dropdown

Comment: Can you share the site with us?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using wrong locator.
Try with this :

```
    WebElement blood_grp=driver_new.findElement(By.name("user_vitals[blood_group]"));
    Select se=new Select(blood_grp);
    se.selectByVisibleText("A +");
```

Comment: Not working..if i use select by id(1) only the i can see it clicks n see dropdown but doesnt select any value

Answer (score 0):

```
Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("user_vitals_blood_group")));
```

select option O + you can do:

```
dropdown.selectByVisibleText("O +");
```

or make it in loop and select it by index

```
dropdown.selectByIndex(i);
```

one more way to do it:

```
try{
    List<WebElement> options = driver.findElement(By.id("user_vitals_blood_group")).findElements(By.tagName("option"));

    for (int i = 0; i < options.Size; i++)
    {
       new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("user_vitals_blood_group"))).selectByIndex(i);
    }

    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: try the second option

Comment: sorry syntax mistake.

Comment: no, it's my mistake try the fixed code (in most i develop in c#)

Comment: there is an exception ? did you see objects in option list ?

Comment: Now also it clicks and display drop down list but doesnt select

Comment: I think when the button before this is selected the page control automatically comes to the drop down will it cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here as I don't know the exact error message you're getting but could be a case of the drop down hasn't loaded yet. In that case I suggest you use a wait to wait for the drop down options to load.

Here's an example of a wait for a drop down to load method that I use -

```
// Method name, pass in the Select element named "dropDown" below
public void waitForDropDownPopulate(WebDriver driver, final Select dropDown) {
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    try {
        wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                List<WebElement> list = dropDown.getOptions(); // Get options in the list 
                //System.out.println("THE LIST SIZE IS: " +list.size());
                if (list.size() < 4) { // if the total items in the list is less than 4 - do nothing
                    //System.out.println("THIS LIST RETURNED FALSE");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    //System.out.println("THIS LIST RETURNED TRUE"); // once it's great than 4 allow the script to continue 
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

So you're code should look like the following now:

```
WebElement blood_grp=driver_new.findElement(By.name("user_vitals[blood_group]"));
Select se=new Select(blood_grp);
className.waitForDropDownToPopulate(driver, se);
se.selectByVisibleText("A +");
```

Comment: waitForDropDownToPopulate is undefined it is coming

Answer (score 0):

At times, visible text has some extra spaces which does not allows to select the value. Try the following code to select the option.

```
 WebElement blood_grp=driver_new.findElement(By.id("user_vitals_blood_group"));
 Select se=new Select(blood_grp);
 se.selectByValue("A +");
```

Comment: I am not talking about space between A and +. There may be space before and after "A +" in the visible text. Try with selectByValue("A +") and see if it works.

Comment: Tried not selecting

Comment: Can you update the exception. As the exception mentioned by you earlier was for the statement.WebElement blood_grp=driver_new.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/form/fieldset[5]/div[1]/select"));

Comment: Its not throwing error now but value not getting selected in dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct to me. It's hard to tell what is going on without being able to see the site for ourselves. Let's do some debugging. The code below should work. Execute it and then post what it is printing. I'm thinking there's something subtle going on.

```
Select bloodGroup = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("user_vitals_blood_group")));
System.out.println(bloodGroup.getOptions().size());
for (WebElement option : bloodGroup.getOptions())
{
    System.out.println(option.getAttribute("outerHTML"));
}
```

Have you tried the different options below? What happens when you try them?

```
bloodGroup.selectByValue("A +");
bloodGroup.selectByIndex(3);
```

---

Now that we know that the code is grabbing the correct `SELECT` and sees the `OPTION`s... what happens if you try the below code.

```
Select bloodGroup = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("user_vitals_blood_group")));
bloodGroup.selectByValue("A +");
```

...or this one...

```
Select bloodGroup = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("user_vitals_blood_group")));
bloodGroup.selectByIndex(3);
```

Comment: OK. I updated the answer... try the two code samples I just added and let me know what happens.

Comment: This should all work. I don't know what else to try or what is wrong without seeing the site for myself.

Comment: Please let me know at what time u will be online will tell the site address

Comment: I am using selenium 3.0.0 beta version , this may be the issue?

Comment: @john I have no idea. The only way to find out is to go back to a non-beta version and see if it works.

Comment: I think its a bug in beta version. I tried for face book singup to select day dropdown its clicking and not selecting any value