# Unable to select and click drop down element using javascript executor

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select an element from the dropdown. As Select and Action classes are not working for me, I am using javascript Executor. While, it's passing the test case, it's not opening the expected screen after clicking. Below is the code snippet.

[HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJqsh.png)

Code:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) webDriver;
js.executeScript("return document.getElementById('1692').selectedIndex = '" + 3 + "'");
```

HTML for drop down button:

```
<a id="1692" name="mItem" nowrap="true" class="itemStyle1Active" style="cursor: pointer;">My Business</a>
```

HTML for element inside the dropdown:

```
<a id="30241" name="mItem" nowrap="true" class="itemStyle" style="cursor: pointer; color: white; background-color: rgb(127, 158, 195);">FA Productivity</a>
```

Comment: HTML for drop down button: 
<a id="1692" name="mItem" nowrap="true" class="itemStyle1Active" style="cursor: pointer;">My Business</a>
HTML for element inside the dropdown:                                                                              <a id="30241" name="mItem" nowrap="true" class="itemStyle" style="cursor: pointer; color: white; background-color: rgb(127, 158, 195);">FA Productivity</a>

Comment: Take help from mentioned link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239278/how-to-select-a-value-from-drop-down-using-selenium

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To select a Value From Drop-Down using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38239278/how-to-select-a-value-from-drop-down-using-selenium)

Comment: Tried it but got this error: javascript error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined